# Facebook development on localhost with MVC

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC facebook app I'm writing but when I run it, I keep getting, "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.".  I have googled this to death and still can't get it working.  I have set up a test application in facebook and I have updated all the app IDs, etc in my web.config.  I added 'localhost' as a domain and https://localhost:port as the URL.  I have yet to get it loaded without this error.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using IIS or IIS Express? If full IIS, have you added the virtual directory in the IIS GUI?

Comment: I'm using IIS Express. I have my solution configured for SSL and the SSL Url set as the project Url.  I used that same Url in the facebook site Url.  I'm tried adding "localhost" as the app domain and leaving the app domain blank.